# how to avoid R fisher.test workspace errors

Tags: r, memory, workspace

I am preforming a fisher's exact test on a large number of contingency tables and saving the p-val for a bioinformatics problem. Some of these contingency tables are large so I've increased the workspace as much as I can; but when I run the following code I get an error:

```
result <- fisher.test(data,workspace=2e9)
LDSTP is too small for this problem. Try increasing the size of the workspace.
```

if I increase the size of the workspace I get another error:

```
result <- fisher.test(data,workspace=2e10)
cannot allocate memory block of size 134217728Tb
```

Now I could just simulate pvals:

```
result <- fisher.test(data, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 1e5)
```

but Im afraid Ill need a huge number of simulations to get accurate results since my pvals may be extremely small in some cases.

Thus my question whether there is some way to preemptively check if a contingency table is too complex to calculate exactly? In those cases alone I could switch to using a large number of simulations with B=1e10 or something. Or at least just skip those tables with a value of "NA" so that my job actually finishes?

Comment: Describe the data better.

Comment: the data for each of the tests is an nx2 matrix of intergers ranging from 0 up to about 300. The size of the matrix varies test to test: 2x2, 10x2, 20x2 etc. I could try to guess which matrices will cause an error (such as the larger ones) and estimate the pval for those but ideally there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you colud use `tryCatch` to get desired behaviour when `fisher.test` fails? Something like this maybe:

```
tryCatchFisher<-function(...){
    tryCatch(fisher.test(...)$p.value,
    error = function(e) {'too big'})
    }
```