# fisher.test crash R with *** caught segfault *** error

Tags: r, statistics, crash

As title said, `fisher.test` crash R with `*** caught segfault ***` error. Here is the code to produce the error:

```r
d<-matrix(c(1,0,5,2,1,90,0,0,0,1,0,14,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,
            0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1,0,2,3,89),
          nrow=6,byrow = TRUE)
fisher.test(d,simulate.p.value=FALSE)
```

I found this, since I use the `fisher.test` inside some functions. Running them on the data produced R to crash with the aforementioned error.
I understand that the table provided to `fisher.test` is ill behaved, but that kind of things should not be happening, I guess.

I would appreciate any suggestions on which conditions should be met by the contingency table in order to avoid this kind of crashes due to the `fisher.test` misbehavior. Also what other arguments should be set in `fisher.test` in order to avoid the crash, I did a little test in which

```r
fisher.test(d,simulate.p.value=TRUE)
```

does not crash and produced a result.

I am asking for this since I will have to implement that to avoid future crashes in my pipeline.

Comment: I can confirm that this crashes on my machine with `simulate.p.value=FALSE` (MacOS, R version 4.1.3) ... and by definition this is a bug, since base R code should never segfault.

Comment: ditto on ubuntu , R 4.2.0

Comment: ditto on WIndows 11/RStudio 2022.02.1 Build 461. But not on command line R nor on Rscript (R 4.2.0).

Comment: ditto ubuntu 20.04, R-4.2.0 terminal

Comment: @BenBolker what is the appropriate way of reporting this to CRAN?

Comment: @NicolasMolano You should read the [guide](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html) for reporting bugs in R. You will need to contact one of the administrators of R's [Bugzilla](https://bugs.r-project.org/) to get permission to create a bug report. Alternatively, I can report the bug for you once I'm at my computer, if no one else has already.

Comment: https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18336

Comment: This may be impractical/require a gigantic workspace to compute (exact tests can get very computationally demanding with large tables/large entries in the tables), but it definitely shouldn't segfault -- instead it should give you a meaningful error about needing to increase the workspace (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241566/how-to-avoid-r-fisher-test-workspace-errors )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that this is a bug in R 4.2 and that it is now fixed in the development branch of R (with [this commit](https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/df482443619bae031f11c627026f039db8ac0584) on 7 May). I wouldn't be surprised if it were ported to a patch-release sometime soon, but that's unknown/up to the R developers. Running your example above doesn't segfault any more, but it does throw an error:

> Error in fisher.test(d, simulate.p.value = FALSE) :
> FEXACT[f3xact()] error: hash key 5e+09 > INT_MAX, kyy=203, it[i (= nco = 6)]= 0.
> Rather set 'simulate.p.value=TRUE'

So this makes your workflow better (you can handle these errors with `try()`/`tryCatch()`), but it doesn't necessarily satisfy you if you really want to perform an *exact* Fisher test on these data. (Exact tests on large tables with large entries are *extremely* computationally difficult, as they essentially have to do computations over the set of all possible tables with given marginal values.)

I don't have any brilliant ideas for detecting the exact conditions that will cause this problem (maybe you can come up with a rough rubric based on the dimensions of the table and the sum of the counts in the table, e.g. `if (prod(dim(d)) > 30 && sum(d) > 200)` ... ?)

Setting `simulate.p.value=TRUE` is the most sensible approach. However, if you expect precise results for extreme tables (e.g. you are working in bioinformatics and are going to apply a huge multiple-comparisons correction to the results), you're going to be disappointed. For example:

```r
dd <- matrix(0, 6, 6)
dd[5,5] <- dd[6,6] <- 100
fisher.test(dd)$p.value 
## 2.208761e-59, reported as "< 2.2e-16"
fisher.test(dd, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 10000)$p.value
# 9.999e-05
```

`fisher.test(..., simulate.p.value = TRUE)` will never return a value smaller than `1/(B+1)` (this is what happens if *none* of the simulated tables are more extreme than the observed table: technically, the p-value ought to be reported as "<= 9.999e-05"). Therefore, you will never (in the lifetime of the universe) be able to calculate a p-value like 1e-59, you'll just be able to set a bound based on how large you're willing to make `B`.